# How to filter out a list of particular nodes using Gremlin

Tags: titan, gremlin

I am using `Titan` and `Gremlin 3.0.1`

The graph only has one type of node which is `"nodeA"` and has five edge labels, namely `"relation1"`, `"relation2"`, etc.

Now I want to find the nodes which do not have `"relation1"` or `"relation2"` edges. Below is the query I am using:

```
g.V().except(g.V().in('relation1', 'relation2'))
```

This gives the error: `"the wrong type of argument for except"`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`except` is not a step in TinkerPop 3. All you need is the `not` step:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().not(bothE("created"))
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().not(outE("created"))
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
gremlin> g.V().not(inE("created"))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```